# update email category using microsoft graph

Tags: python, html, graph, outlook, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to use PATCH and microsoft graph to update the categories of my emails.

But i am not sure how to proceed

```
def get_my_messages(access_token):
  get_messages_url = graph_endpoint.format('/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages')

  # Use OData query parameters to control the results
  #  - Only first 10 results returned
  #  - Only return the ReceivedDateTime, Subject, and From fields
  #  - Sort the results by the ReceivedDateTime field in descending order
  query_parameters = {'$top': '10',
                      '$select': 'receivedDateTime,subject,from,categories',
                      '$orderby': 'receivedDateTime DESC'}

  r = make_api_call('GET', get_messages_url, access_token, parameters = query_parameters)

  if (r.status_code == requests.codes.ok):
    return r.json()
  else:
    return "{0}: {1}".format(r.status_code, r.text)
```

I am able to retrieve emails at the moment

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, You need to [List Outlook categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-list-mastercategories?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to find the categories' id you want to update.

```
GET /me/outlook/masterCategories
```

Then you can [Update Outlook category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-list-mastercategories?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) by calling this endpoint:

```
PATCH /me/outlook/masterCategories/{id}
```

Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookcategory-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example).

Comment: The question is about changing the category of one mail. It is not about creating categories for my mailbox.